# "Incompatible Types" while trying to return arraylist from method

Tags: java, arraylist

In this class, I'm wanting to return an arraylist in whole, not as individual elements. However, I'm getting an error, "Incompatible Types" at compilation time. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for any and all of your help!!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class CO2FromElectricity
{



/**
 * Constructor for objects of class CO2FromElectricity
 */
public CO2FromElectricity()
{

}

public static double calcAverageBill(ArrayList<Double> monthlyBill, int ind) 
{
  ArrayList<Double> avgBill = new ArrayList<Double>();
  int i = ind;
  avgBill.set(i, (monthlyBill.get(i) + avgBill.get(i))/2); 
  return avgBill.get(i);    
}

public double calcAveragePrice(ArrayList<Double> monthlyPrice, int ind)
{
    int i = ind; 
    ArrayList<Double> avgPrice = new ArrayList<Double>();
    avgPrice.set(i, (monthlyPrice.get(i) + avgPrice.get(i))/2);
    return avgPrice;
}

public double calcElectricityCO2(double avgBill, double avgPrice)
{
    double avBill = avgBill;
    double avPrice = avgPrice; //Price per kilowatt that is...
    double emissions = (avBill/avPrice)*1.37*12; 
    return emissions;

}
}
```

Comment: In the future, post the stack trace.  Also, the stack trace is most assuredly giving you the line number, which clearly is returning the wrong type.

Comment: I have honestly never heard of a "Stack Trace" - the things computer class doesn't teach, LOL. Thanks!

Comment: My error.  In this case, you would include the compiler error.  A stack trace is a runtime error.  You will know it when you see it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public double calcAveragePrice(ArrayList<Double> monthlyPrice, int ind)
```

The method expects to return a double.

```
ArrayList<Double> avgPriAce = new ArrayList<Double>();
...
return avgPrice;
```

You are returning an arrayList. Change your code to be like this:

```
public ArrayList<Double> calcAveragePrice(ArrayList<Double> monthlyPrice, int ind)
```

And that should fix it.

---

On second thoughts your method is doing something really weird. I am sure you do not want an arraylist as an average. You definitely want a double as an average.

If my assumptions are correct, you are trying to add up every value in the monthlyPrice and return the average? In which case you need to loop over every value in the array and add them up and divide by the number of elements to get the mean value and return that as a double. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 4):

In the `calcAveragePrice()` method you're returning a `List`, while the method is defined to return a `double`.

***Either*** change the method signature to

```
public List<Double> calcAveragePrice(...)
```

***Or*** return a `double`

```
return list.get(i); //similar to the getAverageBill() method
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public ArrayList<Double> calcAveragePrice(ArrayList<Double> monthlyPrice, int ind) {
    int i = ind;
    ArrayList<Double> avgPrice = new ArrayList<Double>();
    avgPrice.set(i, (monthlyPrice.get(i) + avgPrice.get(i)) / 2);
    return avgPrice;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your calcAveragePrice is returning a List (as the others already mentioned).

It also doesn't make any sense though. You create the list at size 0, but then you try to set into the list at an index that wont exist (because the list is empty) and then you return it. This function even if you fix it so it compiles will always throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException unless ind is 0.

Most likely you don't want a list at all, if you do want a list you need to use it properly.

Comment: [`List.set()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) won't necessarily fail because of how it checks the range `(index < 0 || index >= size())` (the important bit being less than or *equal to* `size()`). This, of course, is still playing with fire if you're not passing just the right index values to that method.

Comment: It will throw a IndexOutOfBoundsException for all cases of index as the list is always size 0, read the code.

Comment: Read the docs. If the list is empty, it has size of `0`. If OP happens to pass `0` as the value of `ind`, which gets assigned to `i`, then `list.set(i, ...)` will not fail, it will instead insert the element into the list. I'm not defending the logic that OP is using, it's prone to fail, but it's not *guaranteed* to fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
public double calcAveragePrice(ArrayList<Double> monthlyPrice, int ind){ 
// return type is double    
int i = ind; 
ArrayList<Double> avgPriAce = new ArrayList<Double>();
avgPrice.set(i, (monthlyPrice.get(i) + avgPrice.get(i))/2);
return avgPrice; // you are returning  a list. This is Incompatible
 }
```

Change your code as to achieve what you want `I'm wanting to return an arraylist in whole, not as individual elements`

```
public List<Double> calcAveragePrice(ArrayList<Double> monthlyPrice,int ind){  
List<Double> avgPrice = new ArrayList<Double>();
// your implementation 
return avgPrice; // you are returning  a list
}
```

Comment: Will still boom. Index out of bounds at run time.

Comment: @TimB what are you talking about ? I am not going to code for OP. I just point outed the issue.

Comment: The code you posted was still invalid, it only fixed half the problem. You've fixed it now though. (It wasn't me downvoted you so I can't remove the downvote)